# no DTD found in Symfony2.3

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I am using Symfony2.3 _ Sonata Admin + Sonata E-commerce Bundle All installation is successfully done.

But When I go Back-end url as login then show me :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("[ERROR 522] Validation  failed: no DTD found ! (in n/a - line 2, column 21)
[ERROR 1877] Element '{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}trans-unit': Duplicate key-   sequence ['sonata.invoice.references.date'] in key identity-constraint    '{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}K_unit_id'. (in /var/www/xyz.com/web/ - line 172, column 0)") in SonataUserBundle:Admin:Security/login.html.twig at line 14.
```

I don't know why ?
I am totally confuse?
Any one know this ?

Comment: where are you confused? It is saying here, login.html.twig. check your translation file, there must be two entries having same translation key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this has been fixed here: https://github.com/sonata-project/ecommerce/commit/1aee2f8f78eb38a42b5f84260348262af8c2312d#diff-d0af37f82ac64ab8fc32c34c2f39b110

You should update your dependencies to fix the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably duplicated translation key in your translation file. Symfony can't create translation cache files.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is Sonata E-commerce Bundle issue and It was fixed.